# To be singular to something

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions

After lots of searching and googling, I was not able to find any sense or meaning for the expression "`is singular to`" in the sentence below:

> The capacity to release this pure language **is singular to** translation.

Could any one help me, please?

---

*References would be really appreciated.*

Comment: Huh.  Sounds like an awkward paraphrase of "unique to" to me.

Comment: @Mary Not sure, although the context makes a similar inclination in my mind, too! need ref. Thanksss

Comment: As per the first comment, a [synonym](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/singular) of **singular** is **unique**. I wouldn't personally say it's awkward phrasing, however. I see *singular* used in the sense of *unique* quite often. It is, however, less common than just using *unique*.

Comment: @JasonBassford , Thanksss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author means "unique".

> *References would be really appreciated.*

[wiktionary.com](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/singular#English)

> 2. Being the only one of the kind; unique.
>      She has a singular personality.

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/singular?s=t)

> 3. being the only one of its kind; distinctive; unique:
>      a singular example.